# Could not resolve dependency: peer tslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from codelyzer@5.2.2 node_modules/codelyzer dev codelyzer@"^5.1.2" from the root project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, primeng

I'm having problems creating my angular project, I've already tried updating @angular / core
tried to delete a node modules folder and install again
I changed the version of my node and npm
Nothing works

This is the error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdywP.png

This is my tsconfig.json

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": { "@angular/.*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"] },
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

this is my angular.json

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "TanderDelivery-WebApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/TanderDelivery-WebApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "TanderDelivery-WebApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "TanderDelivery-WebApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "TanderDelivery-WebApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "TanderDelivery-WebApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "TanderDelivery-WebApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "TanderDelivery-WebApp"
}
```

And my package.json

```
  "name": "tander-delivery-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.13",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.0.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

I don't know what else I need to do

Comment: Primeng versions match up to angular versions. If you are using ng v9, you should also use primeng v9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by installing codelyzer globally

`npm install -g codelyzer`

I deleted `node_modules`  and installed it again with

`npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Approved solution didn't work for me.

The solution that I found was:

1. Manually updating the `package.json` and setting `"tslint": "^6.0.0"` under `devDependencies`
2. Manually updating the `package-lock.json` to `"tslint": "^6.0.0"`
3. Deleting my `node_modules` folder
4. Running `npm ci` (installing all node packages according to the `package.json` and `package-lock.json`)
5. Running `npm audit fix`